# Condition for a particle to move on a sphere

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

Is it possible for a particle of mass $m$ to complete a circular path on a sphere if it starts from the topmost point and no external force acts on it except gravity and frictional force between sphere and the particle?

If yes, what are the conditions for it?

Comment: It has to have an initial velocity in order for the particle to move away from the equilibrium point (top).

Comment: generally it will leave the sphere before completing a quarter of a cycle.

Comment: Is the gravity due to the sphere itself, or are you considering a massless sphere sitting on the surface of the earth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short Answer - No

Refer to the figure below:
[image]

If you draw free body diagram of the particle at a point beyond C you will notice that there is no force acting towards the surface of sphere. Hence it won't be able to complete the circle beyond point C whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Under normal conditions and size of the sphere the answer is no because the gravitational pull of the earth would attract the particle towards its centre. If the size of the sphere is bigger than the size of earth then the gravitational pull provided by the sphere will cancel out the g effect of the earth and the net gravitational pull will provide the necessary centripetal force to the particle to move around the sphere.